# Python Api Request, Session expired

Tags: python, session, request

I'm trying to translate

```
    curl -k 'https://'adresse_IP':443/?\{%22request%22:%22postRequest%22\}' --data '? 
    {"request":"login","data":{"login":"user","password":"password"}}' --cookie-jar ./cookiefilename
```

In python (2.7)

So i tried first :

```
   data = { 'request' : 'login', 'login' : 'user', 'password' : 'password' }
   url_token = "https://ip:443?\?\{%22request%22:%22postRequest%22\}"
   r_token = requests.post(url_token, json.dumps(data), verify=False)
```

but without success

```
  {"responseStatus":["SEX","SESSION_EXPIRED"],"reloadUserProfile":false}
```

So i tried to fixed the session issue

```
  s = requests.Session()
  r = s.post(url_token, json.dumps(data), verify=False)
```

But Same issue

```
 {"responseStatus":["SEX","SESSION_EXPIRED"],"reloadUserProfile":false}
```

The user works in curl ( bash )

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the Content-Header, and you should use the keyword `data` in front of `json.dumps(data)`. Change:

> ```
> r = s.post(url_token, json.dumps(data), verify=False)
> ```

to:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
requests.post(url_token, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

The `json` keyword was introduced in requests version 2.4.2 and it will set the right Content-Header too. So with new versions of requests you can do:

```
r = s.post(url_token, json=data)
```

---

**Edit:**

I think you also need to change `data` to the following to match your curl request:

```
data = {"request":"login","data":{"login":"user","password":"password"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

i added like you told me

   data = { 'request' : 'login', 'login' : 'user', 'password' : 'password' }
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   url_token = "https://ip:443?\?\{%22request%22:%22postRequest%22\}"
   r_token = requests.post(url_token,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=False)'
unfortunately same issue

Kind Regards

Comment: @MaximusJones I think you got the `data` wrong. See my edit above.

Comment: It seems if i use https://ip:443?\?\{%22request%22:%22postRequest%22\} the request is well configured but not with https://ip:443

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
 'https://<adresse_IP>:443'
```

By

```
data = { 'request' : 'login', 'login' : 'user', 'password' : 'password' }
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    url_token = "https://ip:443?\?\{%22request%22:%22postRequest%22\}"
    r_token = requests.post(url_token, json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=False)'
```

Answer

```
{"responseStatus":["F","REQUEST_UNDEFINED"],"reloadUserProfile":false}
```

I guess I'm codding badly the request.